# How do you import a spreadsheet into DB2?

Tags: eclipse, db2, etl

I have a CSV file, but this could apply to any txt, data, or xls file.  (xlsx)  I have exported the data from one source and I want to *import the data into a DB2 table*.

I first tried **Data Tools Plugin (DTP)** in eclipse Helios (3.6.3) by right clicking on the table and selecting: **Data > Load...**

But I got this error:

> Loading "myschema"."mytable"... com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException:
>   [jcc][10103][10941][4.14.113] Method executeQuery cannot be used for
>   update. ERRORCODE=-4476, SQLSTATE=null Data loading failed.

Then I tried **Eclipse SQL Explorer** on Eclipse Juno, but it [does not support data import](http://sourceforge.net/p/eclipsesql/discussion/450662/thread/a8645d30).

How do I get past this error so I can import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by installing **Eclipse Juno (4.2)** and **Data Tools Plugin (DTP) 1.10.2**.

Now **Data > Load...** will work fine.  This is the new message I get:

> Data loading was successful. 142 row(s) loaded. 135 row(s) could not
>   be loaded.
>
> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.go: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502,
>   SQLERRMC= , DRIVER=4.7.85 One or more values could not be set in the
>   following column(s): USER_TIME, USER_DATE

---

FYI for the entire process I was using this:

- DB2 driver: /opt/IBM/db2/V9.7/java
- With jar files: db2jcc4.jar, db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar
- Driver Class: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

Answer (score 3):

You can import a CSV file directly into DB2 via the IMPORT or LOAD command, even with XML or BLOB as part of the data to import.

The procedure to import depends on the structure of the file you are going to import. Probably you should modify the default behaviour of these commands; DB2 has many option to adapt the command to the input file.

For more information about:

- The import command: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html
- The Load command http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html

I think your question was more oriented to: how to use Eclipse to import data in DB2 from a CSV file. However, as I said, you can do that directly via DB2.

If you are going to import a file like the next one, the only thing that you need is to have access to a db2 client.

data.txt

```
1,"Andres","2013-05-18"
2,"Tom","2011-04-16"
3,"Jessica","2002-03-09"
```

You import with

```
db2 import from data.txt of del insert into test
```

Comment: It's great to learn other ways too.  Thanks for the answer.  Can you edit your answer to show an example of both `IMPORT` and `LOAD`?  It would make the answer even better.  Can you run these commands just as you would an SQL statement?

Answer (score 2):

You can import using DB2 "[Control Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/ims/imscc/)" `*`

Right Click the table and select "Import"

[image]

Then specify the csv file and message file
message file is important because in the case of failed upload, you can find the error cause in the message file

[image]

`*` Control Center is now deprecated in favor of "[Data Studio](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1201migctrlctrdatastudio/)"

Answer (score 2):

From the db2 console, try this:

```
Import from 'yourcommaseparatedfile.csv' of del insert into "SCHEMA"."TABLE"
```

Regards =)

Comment: Same as the answer by @Vikky?

Answer (score 0):

```
db2 'import from /users/n0sdsds/test.csv of del insert into ENTPRISE.tmp_x'
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.